# Mail attachment name's encoding issue in javamail, due to difference between RFC 2047 and pre-2047

Tags: email, jakarta-mail

all

Recently, I am building up a mail system for our company.

And here I got some problem in handling the mail attachment name encoding.

The problem is that in the protocol before RFC-2047, the size of an encoded string should be less than 75 bytes, and this is what java mail did by default.

```
doEncode(string, b64, jcharset, 
 // As per RFC 2047, size of an encoded string should not
 // exceed 75 bytes.
 // 7 = size of "=?", '?', 'B'/'Q', '?', "?="
 75 - 7 - charset.length(), // the available space
 "=?" + charset + "?" + encoding + "?", // prefix
 true, encodingWord, outb);
```

But some of our customer do not recognize this kind of attachment' name

the attachment's name looks like

```
=?UTF-8?B?ABCDEFG=?=
```

So, I manually write a function to encode them without divide them into string less than 70 bytes

BUT AGAIN......

some of our other customers can not recognize our attachment name, and the "UTF-8" name shows up again...

My question is: is there any way that I can do to detect which kind of protocol my customer accept? So I can choose which kind of encoding function I can use...

Comment: [Why doesn't JavaMail properly encode and decode filenames in non-ASCII character sets?](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#encodefilename)

Comment: No, there's no way to detect which broken mailer your customer is going to use to read your messages.